# __autoload is not executing in PHP

Tags: php, autoload

So I am trying to autoload classes in PHP; however, the `__autoload()` function does not seem to be executing. Even I try `echo`ing the `$class_name` variable, I don't see anything except the output I have provided below. I have included all of the relevant files and stripped out the irrelevant parts of it. According to a note in [PHP: Autoloading Classes - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), I cannot use `__autoload()` in CLI [interactive mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), which I am not using. Any pointer will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Output of index.php:

**Fatal error**:  Class 'Calendar' not found in **/home1/tylercro/public_html/cb-test/index.php** on line **3**

index.php:

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['INCLUDES'] . 'prep.php');
    $smarty -> assign('calendar', new Calendar());
?>
```

prep.php:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);

    function __autoload($class_name) {
        include($_SERVER['CLASSES'] . $class_name . '.php');
    }
    require_once($_SERVER['SMARTY_BIN'] . 'Smarty.class.php');

    $smarty = new Smarty();
?>
```

.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes

SetEnv CLASSES /home1/tylercro/public_html/cb-test/includes/classes/
SetEnv INCLUDES /home1/tylercro/public_html/cb-test/includes/
SetEnv SMARTY_BIN /home1/tylercro/smarty/
```

Comment: Always try to build your application without using `.htaccess` - it will helps you to move to nginx.

Comment: As this site is in active development, files get moved around a lot. Do you have any alternative recommendation as to how I can implement the same behavior with as little (or less somehow?) potential required maintenance?

Comment: well, definitely autoloading shouldn't be done with using "magic" $_SERVER constants, declared somewhere. Read this [standard](http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal?pli=1) about using namespaces and class names, and there you will find example of autoloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [post](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=16819#62606) solved my issue. All I had to do was change **prep.php** to the following:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);

    function __autoload($class_name) {
        include($_SERVER['CLASSES'] . $class_name . '.php');
    }
    define('SMARTY_SPL_AUTOLOAD',1);
    require_once($_SERVER['SMARTY_BIN'] . 'Smarty.class.php');
    spl_autoload_register('__autoload');

    $smarty = new Smarty();
?>
```

Comment: define('SMARTY_SPL_AUTOLOAD',0); does it for me - Smarty-3.1.2

Answer (score 4):

Smarty has its own autoload function, and it collides with yours. [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) can solve your problem, as it can register any function as an autoloader.

Comment: I took a look at the documentation which rendered me puzzled. I'm not too sure how to use the function? And what is `spl_autoload()`?

Comment: I registered my `__autoload()` function after I renamed it to `my_autoload()`, but now I get warnings for some Smarty files which I assume are to be autoloaded with Smarty's autoload function. By the way, shouldn't redeclaring `__autoload()` issue a warning or error? Why did I not get that error previously?

Comment: I guess it'd be helpful to mention that it autoloaded the Calendar class.